# Is it possible to use SCP protocol to download files without opening port 21?

Tags: ftp, scp, winscp

Is there any way to download files using SCP without opening port 21 or any other port.I dont have much idea about SCP. If I can get some guidance on any way of doenloading files without opening ports.Please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to download files using SCP without opening port 21

The SSH server can listen on any port that isn't already in use

> or any other port

No